# PHP Array Group and sum

Tags: php, arrays, sum

This is my array:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [great] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [great] => 3 ) [4] => Array ( [bad] => 5 ) [5] => Array ( [calling] => 4) [6] => Array ( [great] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [bad] => 3 ))
```

I want to get this, sum of same names:

great:**`11`**
bad:**`8`**
calling:**`4`**

And also to order from highest sum to lowest.

Any help?

Comment: That doesn't look like your full array, it's missing Array[0].

Comment: Please provide the full, correct array, as well as what you have tried.  There's several problems with your array that make it clear this is not your *actual* array.

Comment: It would be much easier if you post the complete code, if that array comes from a DB you can do that directly in the SQL query

Comment: My array has 448 lines, and it's start from 1. Isn't from SQL,it's making inside the loop $c[$i]=array($ime=>$zbir); Where $ime is great, bad, calling, and $zbir is 5,3,5,4,3,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over each element and:

- if there is no key in the sums array, create a key
- otherwise add the number to the previous sum

```
<?php

$array = array(
    1 => array('great' => 5),
    2 => array('great' => 3),
    4 => array('bad' => 5),
    5 => array('calling' => 40),
    6 => array('great' => 3),
);

$sums = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $label => $count) {
        // Create a node in the array to store the value
        if (!array_key_exists($label, $sums)) {
            $sums[$label] = 0;
        }
        // Add the value to the corresponding node
        $sums[$label] += $count;
    }
}

// Sort the array in descending order of values
arsort($sums);

print_r($sums);

foreach ($sums as $label => $count) {
    print $label.': '.$count.' ';
}
```

[`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) is used to sort the sums by descending values.

This will print this:

```
Array
(
    [calling] => 40
    [great] => 11
    [bad] => 5
)
calling: 40 great: 11 bad: 5
```

[Result in Codepad](http://codepad.org/3NkcX2mX).